# Combine array and add values if key is the same

Tags: php

The title pretty much says it all. I am trying to combine arrays if the date matches the other dates within that specific array with the same project id. So for example have. Here is what i have so far.

```
Array
(
    [1488] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => test
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-11 - 2016-07-17
                            [1] => 37
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-04 - 2016-07-10
                            [1] => 51
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-04 - 2016-07-10
                            [1] => 44
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-04 - 2016-07-10
                            [1] => 22
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => Invoice 78554
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-06-13 - 2016-06-19
                            [1] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => Small Move*
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-06-27 - 2016-07-03
                            [1] => 3.5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-05-30 - 2016-06-05
                            [1] => 9.5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like it to look like this...

```
    Array
(
    [1488] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => test
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-11 - 2016-07-17
                            [1] => 37
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-07-04 - 2016-07-10
                            [1] => 117
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => Invoice 78554
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-06-13 - 2016-06-19
                            [1] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [project_name] => Small Move*
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-06-27 - 2016-07-03
                            [1] => 3.5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2016-05-30 - 2016-06-05
                            [1] => 9.5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

this is my code...

```
 $project_hours = array();
foreach($time_recs as $phours){
    $year = date('Y');
    $w =  date('W', strtotime($phours['work_date']));
    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    $time += ((7*$w)+1-$day)*24*3600;
    $return[0] = date('Y/m/d', $time);
    $time += 6*24*3600;
    $return[1] = date('Y/m/d', $time);
    $startend = $return[0]. ' - '. $return[1];

    $project_hours[$phours['project_id']]['project_name'] = $phours['project_name'];
    $project_hours[$phours['project_id']]['hours'][] = array(0 => $startend, 1 => (float)$phours['entry_hours']);
    $project_hours[$phours['project_id']]['project_hours'][] = (float)$phours['entry_hours'];

}

foreach($project_hours as $hours) {
    if (array_key_exists($hours['hours'][1], $project_hours[$hours['hours']][1])) {
        $project_hours[$hours['project_name']]['time'][] += $hours['hours'][1];
    }else{
        $project_hours[$hours['project_name']]['time'][] = $hours['hours'][1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What shall happen if times overlap  or a shorter time session lies fully within the time period of a greater time session. Lets assume there is a time period from 2016-07-11 to- 2016-07-17 and another from 2016-07-12 - 2016-07-13, should the be summed up as well?

Comment: Yes, as long as its within that week. I am struggling to figure this out. It seems so easy but actually trying to wrote it out has been extremely tricky for me.

Comment: It is not easy at all, but we can reduce the complexity a little. It would be easier if you would calculate the the sum for an descrete amount of weeks. Lets say every week in the year 2016. I could give you that.